# css3 rotate google map view very slow on android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have a requirement to implement a feature for showing some address detail(address view) when user tap a maker from google map(map view). I want to use css3 rotate for user experience.

I use below css so that it is working fine in iOS device but part of android devices are very slow.

```
{translateZ(0); perspective:1000px; backface-visibility:hidden;}
```

Another idea is that to set map view visibility to hidden when it rotates.

Do you have any better idea for much DOM rotate performance issue?